# Function returning incorrect output

Tags: java, function, numerical-methods

I'm trying to code an implementation of the fixed iteration algorithm in java - using java because that's what I'm most comfortable with at the moment, although I imagine that there'd be languages more suited to this purpose than java.

My base function is f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 - x - 3 and for fixed point iteration, this changes to g(x) = ((x + 3 - x^4)/2)^(1/2).
This is my code snippet for the function in java:

'''

```
public static double function(double x) {
                return Math.pow(((3 + x - Math.pow(x, 4))/2) , 1/2);
        }
```

'''

My problem is that when I input an x value of 1.0 into the function, I get a value out of the function of 1.0, which is incorrect because the value should be 1.2247...

I need help with why this function is returning an incorrect value - or is there something that I'm doing which isn't right?

Comment: You're using `int` values, use floating-point numbers.

Comment: `1/2` performs an integer division and it gives you the value `0`.  Just use `0.5`.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Most of them are fine.  It is just the `1/2` that is the problem.  But I agree that using floating point literals throughout will signal the intent more clearly to a (human) reader.

Comment: @StephenC You're right, I should have been more specific :/

Answer (score 0):

It might be treating your `double` as an `int` and that's why you lose precision - can you try typecasting the hardcoded values as `double`?

Something like this:

```
public static double function(double x) {
            double a = 3.0;
            double b = 4.0;
            double c = 0.5;
            return Math.pow(((a + x - Math.pow(x, b))*c) , c);
    }
```

Comment: So simple! Recompiled code with suggested corrections, and I get the answer required. It seems like such a silly issue to have! Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Yea ... but Fermi's *"it might be"* theory of why the original code was wrong is incorrect.  And there is no need to introduce any temporary variables.  Or to do any type casting.

Answer (score 0):

That 1/2 at the end will hurt you. You should consider using double parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you changing 1/2 with 0.5, and even if you want to go safer instead of doing:

((3 + x - Math.pow(x, 4))**/2**

you could go with

((3 + x - Math.pow(x, 4))***0.5**